# Cobbler PXE Boot [PXE-E53: No boot filename received]

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, cobbler

### My setup:

```
VirtualBox
DHCP/Cobbler VM server (CentOS 7)
PXE VM Client
```

### DHCP/Cobbler server (1 device setup as NAT) '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3'

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=1b9314dd-2ad7-4bf5-bada-9fb0ca727526
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.56.101
PREFIX=24
```

### DHCP/Cobbler server '/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf'

```
ddns-update-style interim;

allow booting;
allow bootp;

subnet 192.168.56.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
     option routers             192.168.1.5;
     option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
     option subnet-mask         255.255.255.0;
     range dynamic-bootp        192.168.56.101 192.168.56.111;
     default-lease-time         21600;
     max-lease-time             43200;
     next-server                192.168.56.101;
     class "pxeclients" {
          } else {
                  filename "pxelinux.0";
          }
     }

}
```

### DHCP/Cobbler server '/etc/cobbler/settings'

```
next_server: 192.168.56.101
server: 192.168.56.101
```

### Cobbler check

```
[root@dhcp ~]# cobbler check
No configuration problems found.  All systems go.
```

### Mounting .iso for PXE

```
[root@dhcp ~]# mount -o loop CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1708.iso /mnt/
[root@dhcp ~]# cobbler import --path=/mnt/ --name=CentOS-7
```

### PXE Client

```
PXE-E53: No boot filename received

PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM. 
FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.
```

Answer (score 0):

try dhcpd.conf

```
ddns-update-style interim;

allow booting; allow bootp;

subnet 192.168.56.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
     option routers             192.168.1.5;
     option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
     option subnet-mask         255.255.255.0;
     range dynamic-bootp        192.168.56.101 192.168.56.111;
     default-lease-time         21600;
     max-lease-time             43200;
     class "pxeclients" {
        match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "PXEClient";
        next-server 192.168.56.101;
        filename "pxelinux.0";
        }

}
```

this should work if all your clients boot BIOS mode.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  I updated the /etc/cobbler/dhcp.template and /etc/dhcp/dchpd.conf file with those settings and I still receive the same error.  I really appreciate the response though.

Comment: Why don't you get a Wireshark traffic capture, save it as pcap file and uploade it somewhere; the capture will tell us what's going on.

Comment: Here you go.  It's saved as capture1.pcap.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bCbC8wlFD0c-kNTxjhuLtrACD0Wwt-gg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: that capture does no show any DHCP traffic....